# How to assign/remove a class to an accordion if called from a different page

Tags: javascript, jquery, accordion

I am an amateur in JavaScript, I have an accordion with two Divs and I want to display a specific Div (Active) if called from a specific position from another page, simple ID calling doesn't work. the code id given below

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var address=window.location.href;
    if(address.value$=="#div2"){
       $('div > #div1').removeClass('active');
       $('div > #div2').addClass('active');
    }
```

});

in the above code I want to show the 2nd Div as active in the accordion so I passed "**test.html#div2**" as the address for the page, the address variable catches the address, I am not sure about the **.value** thing though. Please Help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`window.location.href` returns a String so the property `value$` shoud be undefined.

If you want to compare the current `hash` with the div then use `window.location.hash`

Use a self defined cache Variable like this:

```
var hashCache = window.location.hash;
```

Then you can see if the hash changes if you compare the curren hash with the cache

```
if(hashCache !== window.location.hash){
   //hash changed!
}
```

If I get you wrong and you want to compare the full url then use `window.location.href` and compare it to a fixed string like this:

```
if(window.location.href !== 'http://example.com'){
   //user is not on the expected page!
}
```

So your code shoud look like this:

```
var hashCache = window.location.hash;
$(document).ready(function(){
    if(window.location.href !== 'http://example.com'){
       $('div > #div1').removeClass('active');
       $('div > #div2').addClass('active');
    }
    //OR
    if(window.location.hash !== hashCache){
       $('div > #div1').removeClass('active');
       $('div > #div2').addClass('active');
    }

});
```

Comment: Thanks Nano, and if I had three or more accordions and If I wanted to compare "(window.location.href)" to the last part of the URL, what do I need to do then?

Comment: If you can recognize the last part with a specific character that does not exist in the wanted part (*like `/`*), you can do that: `var parts = location.href.explode('/')` now you have splittet the location by your character (*in  this case `/`*). After that you just need to get the last element like this: `var compareWith = parts[parts.length-1]`. The value you want to compare it with is now in `compareWith`.